# Configure Azure App Service without public URL

Tags: azure, endpoint, azure-web-app-service, vnet, sql-data-warehouse

I am trying to deploy an Azure App Service from Visual Studio 15.2. Specifically I am trying to deploy this following service: https://github.com/Microsoft/Azure-SQL-DB-auditing-OMS-integration to ingest audit logs from SQL Data Warehouse to OMS. However, due to security concerns, we would like to do so without creating a public endpoint, a url. We have tried configuring it in a VNet but it does not allow you to do so unless the VNet has a public gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Configure Azure App Service without public URL

As far as I know, we couldn't configure Azure App Service without public URL. If you created a web app, it will auto provide public endpoint for user to access.

Here are two work around.

I found the github application just use the web app's webjobs.

One way:

If you don't need any web site, just use the backgourd process to run the webjobs, you could choose [azure function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) which uses [WebJobs SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk) itself but doesn't require an App Service to be configured for it.

Second way:

Normally we run WebJobs in a Azure App Service web app, and that Azure App Service web app can be accessed/browsed via URL. If you want to prevent users from browsing to that Azure App Service web app, you can add a rewrite rule to site’s web.config to [block web access](http://ruslany.net/2014/04/azure-web-sites-block-web-access-to-non-production-deployment-slots/).

The web.config is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Block unauthorized traffic to staging sites" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <!-- Enter your staging site host name here as the pattern-->
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*" />
            <!-- Enter your white listed IP addresses -->
            <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="123\.123\.123\.1" negate="true"/>
            <!-- Add the white listed IP addresses with a new condition as seen below -->
            <!-- <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="123\.123\.123\.2" negate="true"/> -->

          </conditions>
          <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden"
        statusDescription="Site is not accessible" />

        </rule>

      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

More details about how to add the web.config to your web app, you could follow this steps:

1.Open kudu tool in web portal.

[image]

2.Open cmd console and locate the \site\wwwroot folder.

[image]

3.Create web.config and copy the settings in it.

[image]

4.When we accessed the web site, you could find this:

[image]

Comment: okay, I got the second solution to work using the web.config. Thank you so much for the solution!